# jQuery popover buttons (php)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, yii2

I have a a button to generate presentations. I generate 8 presentation with one click, and then I can edit each one by clicking on its name. There I have another, smaller form. I want to have also some button there, that will let me choose which fields I want to edit. This applies to "place" part - you can specify the place, if you want to. I have a button to show/hide fields connected to place edition.

```
<div>
  <?= 
Html::button(Yii::t('app', 'Add new place'), [
'id' => "add-different-place-btn",
'class' => 'btn btn-success',
])
?>
  <?= 
Html::button(Yii::t('app', 'Delete new place'), [
'id' => "delete-different-place-btn",
'class' => 'btn btn-success',
])
?>
</div>
<br />
<div id="place-hidden-different">
  <div id="place-name-hidden">
    <?= $form->field($place, "[{$index}]name")->textInput()->label(Yii::t('app', 'New place')) ?>
  </div>
  <div id="place-city-hidden">
    <?= $form->field($place, "[{$index}]city")->textInput() ?>
  </div>
  <div id="place-street-hidden">
    <?= $form->field($place, "[{$index}]street")->textInput() ?>
  </div>
  <div id="place-postcode-hidden">
    <?= $form->field($place, "[{$index}]post_code")->textInput() ?>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Then, in my jQuery part I figured out something like this. Notice that I'm really new to jQuery, so it can be something really obvious :)

```
$('.btn-popover-link').on('click', function () {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#place-hidden-different').hide();
    $('#delete-different-place-btn').hide();

    $('#add-different-place-btn').on('click', function () {
      $('#place-hidden-different').show();
      $('#add-different-place-btn').hide();
      $('#delete-different-place-btn').show();
    });

    $('#delete-different-place-btn').on('click', function () {
      $('#place-hidden-different').hide();
      $('#add-different-place-btn').show();
      $('#delete-different-place-btn').hide();
    });
  });
});
```

But, instead of getting what I want to, I get things like that:

[image: First]

It looks ok. But it doesn't work. Nothing happens on clicking "Dodaj nowe miejsce" (Add new place). Morover, in other presentation I get full variety of that form - example below. None of the buttons is working at all, in some popovers there are no buttons at all, in some just not working.

[image: Second]

**What can cause this situation?**

Comment: If I get it well, you are using the same ID `add-different-place-btn` for each of the 8 presentations button.
If this is right, the code is working as expected : ID *must* be Unique !

You should move to class selector as you did with `.btn-popover-link`

Also you should move `$('.btn-popover-link').on('click', function () {}` inside the `document.ready` ;)

Comment: @GrégoireFruleux Wow. So simple. Thanks! Add this comment as an answer, so I can accept it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it well, you are using the same ID `#add-different-place-btn` for each of the 8 presentations button.
If this is right, the code is working as expected: **IDs must be unique** !
You should move to a class selector like you did with `.btn-popover-link`.

Also you should move `$('.btn-popover-link').on('click', function () {});` inside the `$(document).on("ready", function() { ... here ... });`.
Even better with `$(window).on("load", function() {});` but it depends on the kind of code you are running.